# Signs in reduction of belly fat

Tags: cardio, abdominals, bellyfat

I am doing cardiovascular and weight training excercise since past two months. Also, I am following strict diet habits (more protein and vegetables). 
What I am observing is that my abdominal region has become soft/spongy, but its size has not reduced, rather it appears more bulgy.

Is that right or wrong?

I understand that it takes long time to reduce belly size, but I want to know what the signs are in the abdominal region that appear within that time-span.

Comment: I think you need a bit more detail before we can answer this. Is it softer/spongier than before? What core/abdominal exercises are you doing? What do you mean by "more bulgy"? It's possible that your muscles are developing underneath the belly fat, and that is what is "lumping" your belly, but really hard to tell.

Comment: What the signs are? Less belly. Do yourself a favor and get bodyfat calipers or other means of measuring overall body composition. You can't spot-reduce.

Comment: How are you measuring bulginess and sponginess?

Comment: I agree with @Dave about the [skin calipers](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Calculating-Body-Fat-Percentage.html#Skin-Caliper-Method). Also, what is your [waist circumference measurement](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Waist-Measurements.html)? These two measurements will tell you if you are on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

Bodyfat calipers are a cheap and accurate way to monitor body fat percentage: http://www.muscleandstrength.com/tools/how-to-measure-bodyfat-using-calipers.html

That reference shows the correct method and locations for taking measurements (triceps, biceps, shoulder blade, waist), and a chart that lets you calculate body fat percentage based on those measurements.